# L'emploi de la majuscule initiale avec « inc. » (incorporée) ?

Tags: vocabulaire, anglais, droit-et-justice, majuscules, fréquence-utilisation

Normalement, l'abréviation de « incorporée » (*Nom_de_société* inc.) pour une société (par actions; aussi avec *ltée, enr.*) ne prend pas ([1](https://vitrinelinguistique.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/fiche-gdt/fiche/508111/inc), [2](https://vitrinelinguistique.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/21306/la-typographie/majuscules/emploi-de-la-majuscule-pour-des-types-de-denominations/majuscule-aux-noms-dentreprises), [3](https://vitrinelinguistique.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/21792/les-abreviations-et-les-symboles/les-abreviations/listes-dabreviations/liste-dabreviations-courantes), [4](https://www.noslangues-ourlanguages.gc.ca/fr/cles-de-la-redaction/incorporee-limitee-enregistree)) la majuscule initiale (contrairement à l'[anglais](https://www.britannica.com/dictionary/Inc.)). Or [un corpus](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=inc.%2CInc.&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=fr-2019&smoothing=3) (2019) de ngram semble montrer que la majuscule initiale aurait toujours été plus employée alors qu'[un autre](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=inc.%2CInc.&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=fr-2012&smoothing=3) (2012) montre le contraire.

Qu'en est-il, l'usage a-t-il changé, glisse-t-il de plus en plus vers l'usage de langue anglaise ; connaît-on cet usage dans les pays de la francophonie où cette désignation de la forme de la société est moins/pas connue (où l'on connaît plutôt des acronymes, généralement en majuscules) ?

Comment: _ ltée_? Ça veut dire quoi?

Comment: @Frank Limitée, non ?

Comment: @jlliagre Effectivement. On en apprend tous les jours :-)

Comment: Je ne connais ici que les SA, SARL, SAS etc.

Answer (score 2):

En français Les [abbréviations](https://usito.usherbrooke.ca/articles/aides_%C3%A0_la_r%C3%A9daction/LesPrincipalesR%C3%A8glesDEmploiDeLAbr%C3%A9viation) non conventionelles comme "inc." ne prennent pas de majuscule.

En revanche, toutes les lettres des acronymes sont des majuscules.

Exemples :

> av., bd., chap., vol.
>
> JO, SARL, AG (assemblée générale)

"inc." ou "incorporé(e)" ne correspondant à aucune notion en droit des sociétés Français (*ce qui n'est pas le cas au Canada*), son utilisation sera réservée pour nommer sans traduire des noms de société (e.g. *Apple Inc.*). Dans ce cas, il parait normal de conserver l'orthographe d'origine, avec majuscule.

Comment: Merci ! L'italique (_Apple Inc._) est-il employé dans la réponse (ultimement dans une traduction) pour indiquer que le nom n'est pas traduit/est en langue étrangère ?

Comment: On utilise assez souvent l'italique pour les expressions originelles conservées dans le cadre de la traduction d'un texte (roman, article, ...), avec une note de bas de page faisant référence à cette convention lors de la première occurence.. Mais,, ce n'était pas mon intention dans ma répopse (j'aurais pu utiliser le soulignement ou une autre couleur pour mettre l'exemple en évidence.